# Mean value theorem rolle's theorem

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Suppose that $f$ is continuous on $[0, 2\pi]$ and that $f(0) = f(2\pi)$.

Prove that there exists a $c$ in $[0, 2\pi]$ for which $f(c) = f(c+\pi)$.

Here is what i did: if $f(c) = f(c+\pi)$, then $f(c) = f(c-\pi)$.

$f(c+\pi) = f(c-\pi)$ for which $\lvert{\sin(x)}\rvert$ is the function that comes to my mind, and I'm stuck here. I must use the mean value theorem and maybe Rolle's theorem since it's a question from that section, but $\lvert{\sin(x)}\rvert$ is not differentiable. Yet the question itself doesn't mention anything about differentiability of the function.
Could anyone solve this, please?

Comment: MVT requires differentiability, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first step is wrong: it is **not true** that $f(c) = f(c + \pi)$ implies $f(c) = f(c - \pi)$, unless you extend $f$ to a $2\pi$-periodic function.  Making such an extension doesn't help with the proof, anyway.

---

This problem makes no use of Rolle's theorem or the mean value theorem, which makes sense since they don't tell us anything about differentiability.

**Hint:** Consider the function $g(x) = f(x) - f(x + \pi)$ over $[0, 2\pi]$.  Your goal is to show that there exists a $c \in [0, \pi]$ for which $g(c) = 0$.  If $g(0) = 0$, then you're done.  Otherwise, note that $g(0) = -g(\pi)$, and apply the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: And what happens if i show that $g(c)=0$ and $g(0)=g(\pi)$

Comment: Sorry, I had a mistake there.  See my latest change.   First case is if $g(0) = 0$.

Comment: I mean i proved that $g(0)=g(\pi)$, and what now?

Comment: If $g(0) = 0$, then of course we can just take $c =0$.

Comment: This is the case $n=2$ of the Horizontal Chord Theorem: Let $n\in \Bbb N. $ Let $f:[a,b]\to \Bbb R$ be continuous, with $a<b,$ and $f(a)=f(b).$ Let $r=(b-a)/n.$ Then there exists $x\in [a, b-r$] with $f(x)=f(x+r).$